# iOS, Swift: How to add/extend tap action on same rating control code

Tags: ios, swift, rating

I'm using https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html to implement rating control. I'm using star ratings on more than one screen. I want to implement tap control on stars. How do I extend the ratingButtonTapped function so that I can do something differently in the individual View Controllers where I've added star buttons?

Comment: Do you want that action of Tapping a Star to trigger a function in your view controller? Or do you just want to save the state (which star was tapped) when leaving the view controller?

Comment: Yes I want to trigger a function in VC which will send the selected rating to backend. I've managed to make it work by copying the code in the VC itself and tweaking it instead of using it as IBDesignable. I couldn't figure out how I could trigger a function in the VC using that example Apple code. Any idea?

Comment: OK - going through that Getting Started tutorial, have you been changing it to Swift 4 ? Or are you using it as-is with Swift 3 ?

Comment: I'm on swift 4 and it has been working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options when you want one object (such as your view controller) to "do something" when a value / property in another object changes:

- protocol / delegate pattern
- notification center
- KVO (key value observing)

Each has its pros and cons. Notification center *could* be used, but is not really suitable for this task.

Protocol / delegate pattern is used a lot, and is something everyone should learn.

KVO is perhaps the best option for this specific case, and is also (probably) the easiest to implement.

So, for KVO, you will be telling you view controller to **O**bserve any changes to the **V**alue of the **K**ey `rating` that is a property of your custom `RatingControl`.

Following the tutorial, first change your `rating` definition in `RatingControl.swift` to:

```
@objc dynamic var rating = 0 {
    didSet {
        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }
}
```

we simply added `@objc dynamic` specifiers.

Next, in `ViewController.swift`, add a new var / property, and a function (you can put this above `viewDidLoad()`):

```
var ratingObserver: NSKeyValueObservation!

func ratingChanged(to rating: Int) {
    print("Rating was changed to: \(rating)")
    // do whatever else you want here
}
```

Now, inside `viewDidLoad()`, we'll implement the **O**bserver:

```
    ratingObserver = ratingControl.observe(\.rating, options: [.new]) {
        [weak self]
        (ratingControl, change) in
        self?.ratingChanged(to: change.newValue ?? 0)
    }
```

We've now said: any time the value of `.rating` in the `ratingControl` object changes, send that new value to our `ratingChanged()` func. From there, you can do whatever you want with it - store it, use it to change something else, send it to a backend, etc.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I'll try it out soon.